# How to calculate difference between two dates as day month year using carbon in laravel

Tags: laravel

I want to calculate difference between two dates as day,month and year.

What I did :

```
$year = Carbon::now()->diffInYears($row->entry_date);
$month = Carbon::now()->diffInMonths($row->entry_date);
$day = Carbon::now()->diffInDays($row->entry_date);
$month = $month > 12 ? $month-(12*$year) : $month;
$day = $day>30 ? $day-((365*$year)+($month*30)) : $day;
return '<td>' . $year . ' Year ' . $month . ' Month ' . $day . ' Day ' . '</td>';
```

when i do it this way i am calculating wrong. Is there a method in Carbon to calculate this correctly?

Comment: The logic is wrong because, some years have 365 days, and some months have 31 (or 28/29) days

Comment: Yes. I opened the topic to find the truth of it.

Comment: I have answered another logic, have a try

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I found a short and simple way

```
$time = Carbon::now()->diff($row->entry_date);
return '<td>' . $time->y . ' Year' . $time->m . ' Month' . $time->d . ' Day' . '</td>';
```

Answer (score 2):

You may use some logic like this:

```
$entry_date = Carbon::parse("1992-05-18 00:00:00");

$year   = Carbon::now()->diffInYears($entry_date);
$entry_date->addYears($year);
$month  = Carbon::now()->diffInMonths($entry_date);
$entry_date->addMonths($month);
$day    = Carbon::now()->diffInDays($entry_date);

return '<td>' . $year . ' Year ' . $month . ' Month ' . $day . ' Day ' . '</td>';
```

Answer (score 0):

you can use this but adjust according to your own code

```
public function validationDays_remaining($date){
    
    $valid_date = Carbon::parse($date)->toDateString();
    $valid_date = date('Y.m.d\\TH:i', strtotime($valid_date));
    $today = new \DateTime();
    $today->setTime(0, 0, 0);

    $match_date = \DateTime::createFromFormat("Y.m.d\\TH:i", $valid_date);
    $match_date->setTime(0, 0, 0);

    $diff = $today->diff($match_date);
    $diffDays = (integer)$diff->format("%R%a");
    
    return $diffDays;

}
```

Comment: burada gün farkını verir

Comment: What does "%R%a" in `$diff->format("%R%a")` do for formatting?

Comment: @JerricCalosor difference calculate in days.. like 2 days , 6 days,  -4 days

Answer (score 0):

```
$seconds =  Carbon::now()->diffSeconds($row->entry_date);
CarbonInterval::seconds($seconds)->cascade()->forHumans();
```